# Reading windows event logs with nodejs

Tags: node.js, event-log

Is there any npm package that reads a remote windows system's event logs? I made a quick search along npmjs.org, but couldn't find something proper. Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use powershell and get its result. For example:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('PowerShell.exe Get-EventLog -Newest 5 -LogName "Application"', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I want a solution that's independent of platform, I cannot use PowerShell on a Linux box running my app

Comment: Look at node-powershell npm package. You can use it for remote request to windows machine

Comment: Thanks for the reply, node-powershell runs fine on a windows machine, however how can I run a powershell script on a remote machine and return the output to my node app? I couldn't see an example in documentation.

Comment: You can use attribute -ComputerName. For example, `ps.addCommand('Get-EventLog -Newest 5 -LogName "Application" -ComputerName test');` This command gets 5 newest records from Application event log from remote computer with name 'test'. Also you have to have access rights to the remote computer.

Comment: How to run it with Mac OS + Node JS? @Sanchonn

I've been try it but get response:
`The term 'Get-EventLog/Get-WinEvent' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`